# Pipeline failed if scanning scala files

Tags: scala, gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan

I created Gitlab CI which sends all files in `project` folder to scan in SonarQube, and it's working perfect with python files, but if I add scala files it's failed. My Gitlab CI:

```
image: testimage
variables:
  SONARQUBE_URL: https://sonarqube.com
 stages:
  - PyLint

    pylint:
  stage: PyLint
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script:
    - apt-get install scala -y
    - cd project
    - scalac *.scala 
    - ls
    - cd ..
    - sed -i 's/PROJECT-NAME/'"$CI_PROJECT_NAME"'/g'  sonar-project.properties 
    - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.projectVersion=${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    - echo 'Repository Link:' "$SONARQUBE_URL${CI_PROJECT_NAME}"
```

Some lines from logs:

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 13.545s
INFO: Final Memory: 16M/136M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not execute Findbugs

at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: One (sub)project contains Java source files that are not compiled (/builds/scala/myrepo).
Property sonar.java.binaries was not set, it is required to locate the compiled .class files. For instance set the property to: sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
Sonar JavaResourceLocator.classpath was empty
Sonar JavaResourceLocator.classFilesToAnalyze was empty
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsConfiguration.buildMissingCompiledCodeException(FindbugsConfiguration.java:154)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsConfiguration.initializeFindbugsProject(FindbugsConfiguration.java:124)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor.execute(FindbugsExecutor.java:117)
    ... 31 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: `scalac *.scala`, `One (sub)project contains Java source files that are not compiled`. Why not just use sbt for your project?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add this line in sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.java.binaries=.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).